# Why does Array("1","2","3").join() convert strings to numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript array of numbers like

```
Array("1","2","3")
```

and I want to convert it to a string that preserves the quotes around each number like this

```
'"1","2","3"'
```

But the Array.join() and Array.toString() functions strip the quotes.

```
"1,2,3"
```

How can I convert my Array to a string that preserves quotes?

Comment: You have an array of strings, and when joined, the quotes obviously aren't preserved, as they are the string delimiters

Comment: It is not striping the quotes, that's what `join` does, it builds a string with a comma as separator by default. If you want the quotes you'd have to add them, like `'"'+[1,2,3].join('","')+'"'`

Comment: It's not converting anything to anything nor is it "stripping" anything.  You have the array `["1", "2", "3"]`.  When you call `.join()` on it you get the string `"1,2,3"`.  It's just like if you had the array `["a", "b", "c"]`, what would you expect `.join()` on that to give you?  That's right... `"a,b,c"`.  If you want the quotes in there (for whatever strange reason), then you need to *add* the quotes to the string(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It doesn't.** Quotes around strings are a notation thing, telling the system that you want to create a string; they're not part of the string itself. So when you join ["1", "2", "3"], you get "123", because that's the content of the three strings. It happens to look the same as if they'd been numbers, but this is only a coincidence.

**There are a couple of ways to add quotes to strings.** In general, you need to *escape* them in some way. The easiest way to do this in JavaScript is to put a backslash (\) in front of the character you want to escape, like this:

```
Array("\"1\"","\"2"\","\"3\")
```

If you really want a backslash character, then it looks like two backslashes when you escape it (\\). In fact, I had to do this to type out the backslash in this reply.

**There is another option in JavaScript: single-quoted strings.** In JavaScript, the only difference between a single-quoted string and a double-quoted string is that each type can contain the other kind of quote without having to escape it, so you could do things like this:

```
Array('"1"','"2"','"3"')
```

Or, if you wanted single quotes around the numbers instead of double quotes, you could do this:

```
Array("'1'","'2'","'3'")
```

But be careful about single-quoted strings. **JavaScript treats single-quoted and double-quoted strings *almost* identically, but not all languages do**. For example, in C and C++, single-quoted "strings" can only be one character long, while double-quoted strings can be of any length. Perl, PHP, and Ruby allow both types to be any length, but don't perform variable substitution on single-quoted strings. If the only language you work in is JavaScript, then this isn't a big deal, but it can cause some pitfalls that you'll need to look out for if you use many languages at once.

Answer (score 3):

Quotes to define a string are part of javascript language and not part of the string itself.

You should include quotes on the string if you want them to be joined too

```
Array("\"1\"","\"2\"","\"3\"")
```

Answer (score 2):

The quotes around each number serve to let Javascript know that the objects surrounded by the quotes are in fact, strings, so they're not *part* of the string.

```
Array('"1"', '"2"', '"3"');
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can do like this

```
var a = '\"'+Array("1","2","3").join('","')+'\"'
```